# Partial differentiation of Z with respect to t.

Tags: partial-derivative

> Find $dz/dt$ for $z=e^x \cos y$, where $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$ defined by$$x^3+e^x-t^2-t=1\text{ and }yt^2+y^2t-t+y=0.$$

I try to use chain rule that dz/dt = (dz/dx)(dx/dt)+(dz/dy)(dy/dt), but I don't know how to find dx/dt and dy/dt in this problem.

Comment: Are you sure you mean partial differentiation? This looks a lot like regular differentiation to me.

Comment: Because if we can write x=g(t) and y=h(t),then it should be partial differentiation, we can easily solve it by chain rule, but for this I am not sure.

Comment: Partial differentiation should give an answer of $0$.

Answer (score 1):

For normal differentiation,
$$\dfrac{dz}{dt}=-e^x\sin y\dfrac{dy}{dt}+\cos ye^x\dfrac{dx}{dt}$$
Implicit differentation thus gives
$$3x^2\dfrac{dx}{dt}+e^x\dfrac{dx}{dt}-2t-1=0\\
t^2\dfrac{dy}{dt}+2ty+y^2+2ty\dfrac{dy}{dt}-1+\dfrac{dy}{dt}=0$$
Thus,
$$3x^2\dfrac{dx}{dt}+e^x\dfrac{dx}{dt}-2t-1=0\\
\implies \dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{1+2t}{3x^2+e^x}$$
And
$$t^2\dfrac{dy}{dt}+2ty+y^2+2ty\dfrac{dy}{dt}-1+\dfrac{dy}{dt}=0\\
\implies \dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{1-2ty+y^2}{t^2+2ty+1}$$
Substitute:
$$\boxed{\dfrac{dz}{dt}=-e^x\sin y\dfrac{1-2ty+y^2}{t^2+2ty+1}+e^x\cos y\dfrac{1+2t}{3x^2+e^x}}$$

Comment: I got it, thanks! I never seen this kind of question before, I think I need more practice.

Comment: Note that your question did not ask about partial differentiation - a partial derivative of a function of several variables is its derivative with respect to one of those variables, with the others held constant, so partial differentiation would have made $\dfrac{dz}{dt}=0$.

Comment: Ok,I'll go over this chapter.